# Questions when solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For an ODE like $(y+x) dy = (y-x)dx$, I can divide $(y+x)$,and $dx$ for both sides, but if $(y+x)=0$, I take it to the original equation and get $0=(-2x)dx$, $x^2=c$ ($c$ is an arbitrary constant), if $dx =0$, then $x=c$ ($c$ is an arbitrary constant), I can repeat the steps and get $(y+c)dy=0$. Now, if I just ignore all of them shown above, I got $dy/dx=(y-x)/(y+x)$, it is clear I need to transform the variable, like $u=y/x$,but how about $x =0$. I think these steps must be wrong and superfluous but can not explain why.

Also another question, after the transforming, $y=xu$, calculate the total differential I get $dy=xdu+udx$, can I divide $dx$ from both sides? If $dx=0$,how can I deal with it.

Comment: If you want to divide, then you are stuck separating cases; e.g. writing $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-x}{y+x}$ leaves you to focus on solutions that never have $y=-x$ (not just not everywhere but nowhere). You need to revisit the case where $y=-x$ somewhere afterwards.

Regarding your second question, don't take explicit differential notation too seriously. You can get $\frac{dy}{dx}=x \frac{du}{dx} + u$ from $y=xu$ without going via differential notation at all. That's just the product rule.

Comment: @Ian thank you, then how can I deal with the equation when $y+x=0$

Comment: It turns out to just not make sense; without any sophisticated ideas you can see that the only valid point with this property is $(0,0)$ (since you need the right side to be zero too), which isn't on the curve of any other solution.

Comment: @Ian I regard $y+x=0$ as another condition and under that I get $(-2x)dx=0$, why can not I do in this way

Comment: So first you have to start at $(0,0)$ because $dx$ can't just be zero (the solution can't just be one point, that makes no sense). After that, think about doing something like forward Euler (a numerical method). After one step you move to $(h,0)$ and now *the behavior doesn't converge as $h \to 0$*. The same thing happens with any other method, it is a singularity that you can't sort out.

Comment: In general though this sort of analysis constitutes taking explicit differential notation too seriously, IMO. If you can't write it as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\dots$ and have it make sense at the initial point then the equation doesn't mean anything.